Can a scattered profinite set continuously surject onto a non-scattered profinite set?
A topological space is scattered if every nonempty subset has an isolated point. Are there any continuous surjections from a scattered profinite set to non-scattered profinite set?

Depends on your exact definition of a profinite topological space; nevertheless, it's easy to show that if $f: A \to B$ is a continuous surjection from a scattered Hausdorff space, then a) if $f$ is closed and every point has compact preimage, then $B$ is also scattered; b) if Cantor-Bendixon rank of $A$ is finite, $B$ is scattered. (Proof by induction on CB). I think that rules out most easy wannabe-examples.

I mean the definition here->https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08ZW

Ah so you're saying it's impossible? From a)

No this is not possible. There might be an easier proof than this but I don't know one off the top of my head.
First note that a profinite set is scattered if and only if no non-empty closed subspace of it is perfect (by Cantor-Bendixson analysis). Assume that we have a surjection $f : X \to Y$ from a scattered profinite set $X$ onto a non-scattered profinite set $Y$. By replacing $Y$ with a perfect closed subspace and $X$ by the preimage of that subspace, we may assume that $Y$ is perfect. For any non-empty clopen subset $A \subseteq Y$, let $\alpha_A$ be the Cantor-Bendixson rank of $f^{-1}[A]$. Since Cantor-Bendixson ranks are ordinals, there must be some non-empty clopen $A \subseteq X$ with $\alpha_A$ minimal. By minimality, every non-empty clopen subset $B \subseteq A$ has $\alpha_B = \alpha_A$. This means for any non-empty clopen $B \subseteq A$, $f^{-1}[B]$ contains a point with Cantor-Bendixson rank $\alpha_A$, but $f^{-1}[A]$ itself can only contain finitely many such points (since it is closed) and there are infinitely many pairwise disjoint non-empty clopen subsets of $A$ since $Y$ and therefore $A$ is perfect, so we have a contradiction and no such surjection can exist.

Here's the Stone duality perspective:
Scattered profinite sets (a.k.a. scattered Stone spaces) correspond under Stone duality to superatomic Boolean algebras: $B$ is superatomic if every quotient algebra of $B$ is atomic.
Superatomic Boolean algebras have many equivalent characterizations, see Theorem 1 of Superatomic Boolean algebras, by George Wesley Day. One of these, which Day attributes to Mostowski and Tarski, is that a Boolean algebra is superatomic if and only if every subalgebra of $B$ is atomic. From this characterization, it is clear that the class of superatomic Boolean algebras is closed under subalgebras. Applying Stone duality, this means that the class of scattered Stone spaces is closed under continuous surjections.

Just a long comment on Alex Kruckman's answer. I think there's also another proof using Stone duality which could be of interest.
Suppose $\pi: X \to Y$ is a surjection of profinite sets. Any nonzero flabby sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $Y$ on a profinite set (=injective module over the Boolean algebra) has $\pi^{\times}(\mathcal{F})$ nonzero (because the map from functions on $Y$ to functions on $X$ is injective map so any global section of $\mathcal{F}$ extends) here $\pi^{\times}$ is right adjoint to $\pi_*$
Now if $Y$ is non-scattered the ring of continuous functions is not superatomic and equivalently not semiartinian so by the paper of Trlifaj, Two problems of Ziegler and uniform modules over regular rings, there's a continuous injective module=flabby sheaf on $Y$. This has to $\times$-pullback to a continuous injective on $X$ and this implies by loc. cit. that $X$ is not scattered.
But I think all the proofs by algebra somehow encode the Cantor-Bendixson argument in Hansen's answer.
